# Can't upload image (binary) using Azure DevOps Rest API

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am using Javascript (jQuery) to do a POST to Azure DevOps rest API to upload a simple image. But, I can't manage to get it working.

There isn't much detailed documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/attachments/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#upload_a_binary_file apart from understanding I we need to do a post to this endpoint.

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/wit/attachments?fileName=imageAsFileAttachment.png&api-version=5.0
```

Here is my current code. **I can't figure out how do I send my image over to this endpoint?** My image exists in a data-uri format.

```
var dataURI = $("img#target").attr("src");
    var url = "https://xxx.visualstudio.com/_apis/wit/attachments?fileName=image.jpg&api-version=5.0";

    jQuery.ajax ({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        data: dataURI,
        processData: false,
        contentType: "application/octet-stream;charset=utf-8",
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

Help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I succeeded to upload an image with PowerShell, the script is:

```
$image = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("path/to/image.png")
$apiUrl = https://dev.azure.com/_apis...."
$user = ""
$pat = "my-PAT-here"
$base64authInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user, $pat)))
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $apiUrl -Method Post -Body $image -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64authInfo) } -ContentType application/json (works also with application/octet-stream)
```

**So, the idea is to get the image as bytes array (as binary) and then put it in the body request.**

The format you tried to upload is `dataURI`, try to convert it to Binary, check [this](https://gist.github.com/kapad/5b93b14f8a8b193745807b969b189489) code snippet.

Comment: Hi @shayki when you call the API, do you need to get an access token?

Comment: Hi @Slay, Yes I used a Personal Access Token for authorize to Azure DevOps, see my updated answer.